# How to add data Multiple times in same key

Tags: android, arrays, dictionary, hashmap

[image]

I want to add the values in `HashMap`.

[image].

Now `HashMap` formate is keys integer and value is `ArrayList<String>`. Now when I add data first key add properly then first, second and all. Now back to I want to add data in my 0 key at that type they remove old value replace with new value. how to solve this to take all values like old & new both.

Comment: Source code please.

Comment: You can retrieve value(i.e. arraylist) of key "0" and append new value and update to key 0. Also share your code.

Comment: This is behavior of hashmap,As it takes value with a key,so if new value will be given to hashmap with existing key it will update the value.Please read more about [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

Comment: please click on enter image description...you can see issue.

Comment: please check it.. I have put my source code screenshot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [mcve], _AS TEXT_ . Images of code are not useful. Images of code cause problems for screen readers, and are not indexed by search engines - decreasing your chance of getting an answer. Provide your code as text.